# Yii2 eliminate double horizontal scroll

Tags: scrollbar, yii2

I used `kartik` gridview plugin and I have a gridview with a lot of columns so it generated a horizontal scroll bar. But the page generates 2 scroll bars. One for the gridview and one for the page. How to eliminate the body scroll? and how to make the gridview horizontal scroll sticks so that the user will no longer need to scroll to the bottom in order to see the horizontal scroll?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the body scroll simply try adding  in your  `index  view`

```
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

For the second question could be useful reduce (in pagination )  the number of lines displayed

eg: this way

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new YourModelSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=5;
    ...........
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. Do you have any idea on how to make the gridview scroll sticks???

Comment: I'm investigating. i need more time

Comment: I not found much. I give a suggestion of reduce number of lines. I have update the answer however.

Comment: well thanks for this.. I will just have to give an option for the user as to how many rows he wanted to display and store it in a session. Is this method okay?

Comment: Yes you is a good idea